# shell script to get values of elements in a xml after searching for a particular string

Tags: xml, linux, shell

I am using the following xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<log> 
    <logentry revision="31"> 
        <date>2016-06-07</date> 
        <paths> 
            <path kind="file" action="M">components/C_MyAccountChangePassword.component</path> 
        </paths> 
        <msg>R002</msg> 
    </logentry> 
    <logentry revision="26"> 
        <date>2016-06-07</date>
        <paths> 
            <path kind="file" action="M">applications/Admin_Util.app</path>
        </paths>
        <msg>R001 added comments</msg>
    </logentry>
</log>
```

I have to search for a string like

```
grep "R001"
```

and i need to get the files mentioned in the `<path>` tag .Can anyone please help me how to achieve it . I had tried the few things like

```
grep -A1 "<msg>R001" log.xml | grep "<path>"
```

but not getting the desired output.

Comment: Is every xml tag on a new line as in `edit` or do you have all in one line as you pasted earlier?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by [Stefan Hegny](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2322941/stefan-hegny), `grep` is probably not the best way to deal with extracting data from `xml` tags, but if you are definite about the the formatting of the file as in the OP (as new-line separated entries) you can use the below logic:-

```
grep -B 3 -w "R001" file | awk -F '[<>]' '/path/{print $3}'
```

will produce an output as `applications/Admin_Util.app`

The logic is to get the search-pattern and extract `n` lines before it as needed and deploy `awk` to do the rest. If you are interested in storing the value to a variable in a script, you can ignore new lines using `tr`

```
#!/bin/bash
xmlContent=$(grep -B 3 -w "R001" file | awk -F '[<>]' '/path/{print $3}' | tr -d '\n')
```

Comment: Thanks that was very helpful

Answer (score 0):

Using grep with xml is generally not a good idea. I suggest you use appropriate tools like xslt or xmllint (from [libxml](http://www.xmlsoft.org/))

you might e.g.

```
xmllint --xpath '//logentry[contains(msg,"R001")]/paths/path' your.xml
```

and get

```
<path kind="file" action="M">applications/Admin_Util.app</path>
```

which can easier be postprocessed, or use xsltproc (also from [libxml/libxslt](http://xmlsoft.org/XSLT/)) with an xslt stylesheet to bring the output in a shape that fits your needs.

If your xml was somehow formatted for sure and all `<logentry>`s  being in one line, a normal syntactic regexp based approach might be feasible, but in a general case, e.g. like your sample, all in one line, this ends up hard.